# Formatted Sub string

Tags: c#, substring

I am using C# and have a string with document name:

```
string docName = "email notification 4926-0538-5751 v.11.docx"
```

Here is how it was formated originally:

```
"Doc_Name Doc_Number v.version_Number.doc_extension"
```

Trying to find how should I get sub string from this string like this:

```
string formateddocNumber = "4826-0718-5751 v.11"
```

I feel like I have to use some sort of regular expression. But not sure.

In case this helps, the doc_number is always this format:

```
1234-1234-1234
```

And always have version in this format:

```
v.some_number
```

I can not use docx to match for regex as the extension could be doc or txt or something.

Comment: Can't you just look for three four-digit numbers separated by a hyphen then a space and v.digits?

Comment: You can split the string into spaces with `docName.Split(' ')`

Comment: without going for the regex, you can search for the last occurrence of "v." and go back 17 places and take it from there

Comment: Any solution will work for me. But I just don't know how to. Dave what should be the right code in C# ? or Kin the version number could be one digit or 2 digits. So what would be the substring settings to extract the doc number and version number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is pretty straightforward:

```
string docName = "email notification 4926-0538-5751 v.11.docx";
var regex = new Regex(@"^.+ (\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4} .+?)\.[^.]+$");
var match = regex.Match(docName);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thinks its closer. But I am getting this : "notification 4826-0718-5751 v.2".  how do I remove entire document name ? Also document name could be anything and any numbers. Like  "email notification setup for year 2017 4926-0538-5751 v.11.docx"

Comment: It wasn't fully clear from the question what part exactly do you need. Check update of my answer.